# grep some expression from some logs and only select the ones with positive results

Tags: bash, grep

I'm using 'zgrep' to find some ip's from some apache/nginx logs and I need a way to sort only positive results.

I'm using this:

```
for i in `cat /var/tmp/list_of_ip.txt`; do
    zgrep -arcH $i /webstats/some_website/*/*.2012-10-1{7..9}* ;
done
```

There are lots of log files. I just want to know which ones return positive results.

Most of them will print `0` at the end indicating that there were nothing found, and some will print the number of matches. How can I select only those and output results in a file ?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you show a few lines of output from the current script?

Comment: Also, do you want to see the list of _IPs_ that have a positive hit, or the list of _files_ which have positive matches?

Comment: I need to see the files which have positive matches.

Comment: Do you the IP matter? I mean do you just need the name of all files that contains any IP in `list_of_ip.txt`, or do you need to know which IP is found in each file too?

Comment: I need the names of all files which have positive records. I mean, I need to see all the lines from that logs that have hits from that list of IP's.

Answer (score 4):

You want to avoid decompressing the log files more than once each, so you should use:

```
zgrep -l -F -f /var/tmp/list_of_ip.txt /webstats/some_website/*/*.2012-10-1{7..9}*
```

This will decompress the log files once, run `grep` in `fgrep` mode (`-F`) and read the list of words to look for (IP addresses) from the file (`-f /var/tmp/list_of_ip.txt`), and list only the file names of the files that contain one or more of the matching IP addresses (`-l`).  `fgrep` mode looks for words without metacharacters; if you need metacharacters, I think you can use `grep -E` (with the `-f` option) instead.  You can add the `-r` option of your `-arcH` set as you wish; the others are redundant in this context.

Some casual testing done on Mac OS X 10.7.5 with `zgrep (gzip) 1.3.12` and `grep (GNU grep) 2.5.1`, as reported by the `--version` options.

Comment: +1 for going above and beyond the call to duty!  Personally I've never used zgrep, so I figured my hacky little pipe would work just fine (and technically it will), but in the real world optimizations like this could be the difference between minutes, hours, or days; not to mention disk lifespan!

Comment: yeah, the -F option is sweet, never knew about that

Answer (score 0):

Think I've got it.., just toss another `grep` in there that filers out the results containing ':0' at the end of them!

```
for i in `cat /var/tmp/list_of_ip.txt`
do zgrep -arcH $i /webstats/some_website/*/*.2012-10-1{7..9}* | grep -v :0$
done
```

Comment: Hey `quickshiftin` thanks a lot. Indeed it does work as I was expexting. I filters and only prints the files which contain the ip's from that list. Thank you for that.

Comment: How 'bout you hook a brother up w/ a +1 ?